# SSO login & authenticate Wordpress users with JWT token

Tags: php, security, jwt

I'm in the midst of exploring SSO with JWT & Wordpress, I'm not too sure if it's a good practice or does this setup/flow have any security vulnerabilities.

Currently JWT/SSO method i'm using is based on this [answer/method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33723033/single-sign-on-flow-using-jwt-for-cross-domain-authentication#answer-37392811) which is getting JWT token using iFrame method instead of redirection method eg: from domain1.com > sso.com (retrieve JWT) > domain1.com

Please refer below for my setup/codebase fmi:

**Main SSO domain (using Wordpress and JWT)**

- https://sso.com/login
- https://sso.com/validation

**Platform 1 (using plain PHP)**

- https://domain1.com

**Platform 2 (using plain PHP)**

- https://domain2.com

---

**sso.com/login (Wordpress)**

```
<h3>Passport</h3>
<br>
<input type="text" name="username" value="admin"/><br>
<input type="text" name="password" value="admin"/><br>
<br>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id='submit_btn'>Submit</a>

<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script>
    $(document).on('click','#submit_btn',function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://sso.com/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                username : $('input[name=username]').val(),
                password : $('input[name=password]').val(),
            },
            success: function(data){
                localStorage.setItem('token',data.token);
                //Which means sso.com/validation able retrieve localStorage('token'); too!
            }
        });
    });//endClick
</script>
```

---

**Platform 1 & Platform 2 (PHP)**

*Questions: is it safe if i'm using postMessage to retrieve JWT token from iframe/sso.com? Any security vulnerability i need to concern?*

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Platform 1</title>
</head>
<body>    
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script>
        var passport_url = 'https://sso.com/validation/';
            passport_url+= '?parent='+encodeURI(window.location.href);
        $('<iframe>', {
            src         : passport_url,
            id          : 'passport',
            frameborder : 0,
            scrolling   : 'no',
            style       : 'display:none;',
            width       : 0,
            height      : 0,
        }).appendTo('body');

        var eventMethod  = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
        var eventer      = window[eventMethod];
        var messageEvent = eventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";

        // listen to message from sso.com/validation
        eventer(messageEvent,function(e) {
            alert("Token received: \n"+e.data)
            //got the token! will be authenticate using ajax and redirect to logged in page...  
        },false);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**sso.com/validation (Wordpress)**

*Questions: Since we'll have multiple platform eg: domain1.com, domain2.com, etc, is it a good practice to pass a dynamic parameter in postMessage function using parentUrl?*

```
<script>
    var token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    if(token && is_inIFrame())
    {
        //or using PHP validate "Parent" ... using config/application.php
        var parentUrl = getParameterByName('parent');
            parent.postMessage(token,parentUrl);
    }

    function is_inIFrame() {try {return window.self !== window.top;} catch (e) {return true;}}

    function getParameterByName(name, url) {if (!url) url = window.location.href;name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '\\$&');var regex = new RegExp('[?&]' + name + '(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)'),results = regex.exec(url);if (!results) return null;if (!results[2]) return '';return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, ' '));}
</script>
```

---

tldr; is this the right direction to create SSO/JWT authentication with cross domains with PHP? is above method is a secure way to code it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why an iframe was suggested to you, but I do see some possibilities for vulnerability.

For your platforms, I would validate server-2-server.

Flow:

If client claims to be logged in ( in JS / has token in local storage), send token to the platform itself.

The receiving endpoint (let's say platform1_showProfile.php) sends a curl-request to the SSO platform in order to validate (and or logout/refresh if expired etc)

For performance reasons, you will want to ask yourself whether

1. JWT is only your SSO authentication method while maintaining state on each platform or if you want to go stateless and use the sso-endpoint on each call.
2. WordPress is the right solution for this. Consider setting up an authentication server with slimframework or neoan3